# Sage pay reponse url returning billing address line 1

Tags: opayo

Is there a return variable in sage pay response URL where I can get the customer billing address 1 which customer enter during payment page.

Comment: I have found the solution is that we can use admin api for extracting the payment details

Answer (score 0):

No there is not.

I presume you are using SagePay Form integration. You have to take all the details you need on your site, store them and pass their values to Sagepay to stop your customer having to type them all in again.

You would pass billing info in the encypted field using the variables:

BillingSurname
BillingFirstnames
BillingAddress1
BillingAddress2 (optional)
BillingCity
BillingPostCode
BillingCountry (Usually set to 'GB' for UK.)

I know this is an old question but thought I would answer it anyway,

Best wishes,

Paul.